# What's the Node equvialent to ADO.NET and JDO?

Tags: node.js

So in .NET and Java we have a low level framework for database drivers (ADO.NET and JDO respectively). Does Node have an equivalent or does each database driver expose its own unique API?

Comment: In a word, no.  There are a few community modules which attempt to standardize (e.g. sequelize, orm2) by behaving like ORMs, but no "mid-level" frameworks that are between driver and the runtime.

Comment: Well that sucks, but it isn't entirely surprising. Why don't you move that content into the answer section so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no. There are a few community modules which attempt to standardize (e.g. sequelize, orm2) by behaving like ORMs, but no "mid-level" frameworks that are between driver and the runtime.

FWIW, in about 7 years of Node development, I've not noticed the lack.  And that's after being used to .NET and Java for years.  To be frank, i had moved away from direct use of ADO.NET and JDO well before I got off those languages anyway, favoring things like Hibernate. I really don't think anything is missing.

Comment: A major problem for those ORMs is that is it is a pain in the ass to support new databases. Instead of just creating a new SQL generator, you have to basically recreate the whole ORM for each target database.

Comment: Yeah, but YAGNI.  I can't remember the last time I had to change database engines after a project was up and running.  Not saying it doesn't happen, just that it doesn't happen often enough to matter to me.

Comment: By that argument, the Streams library shouldn't exist either.